# Switching between view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, button, view, viewcontroller

I have three view controllers.  I used the flipsideproject template and then added another view controller.

There is a button on the first view controller that goes to the second view controller.  There is a button on the second view controller that goes back to the first one.  When switching between the first and second, those buttons always work.

It is the same situation with the second and third view controller.  When I try to transfer between the first to second to third and then back to first, it does not work.

(1-->2-->3-->2-/->1) My poorly drawn diagram depicts the situation.

I had all of the back buttons connected to the back IBAction, which I thought was the problem.  I then made another IBAction, but it has not fixed the problem.

1st view controller = MainViewController 
2nd VC = FlipSideViewController 
3rd VC = ChooseAlarmSound

This is for going 2->1 (this is the problem I think. It sometimes works)

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender 
{ 
   [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self]; 
}
```

This is for going 2->3

```
- (IBAction)chooseSound:(id)sender 
{ 
    ChooseAlarmSound *controller = [[[ChooseAlarmSound alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseAlarmSound" bundle:nil] autorelease]; 
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; 
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
}
```

This is for going 3->2

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender 
{ 
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; 
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show The code that you go from 3rd to 1st?

Comment: I never go from 3rd to first.  Thats whats weird.  I always go from 1->2, 2->3, 3->2,  and I can't go 2->1 after I have opened 3.  I can if I haven't opened 3.  Ill post the code.  One sec.

Comment: 1st view controller = MainViewController
2nd VC = FlipSideViewController
3rd VC = ChooseAlarmSound

This is for going 2->1 (this is the problem I think.  It sometimes works)
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}

This is for going 2->3
- (IBAction)chooseSound:(id)sender
{    
    ChooseAlarmSound *controller = [[[ChooseAlarmSound alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseAlarmSound" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

Comment: This is for going 3->2

- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

Comment: You include in your question by pasting it in to the question, then selecting it and pressing the {} button at the top of the edit box, or pressing command-K, or indenting by 4 spaces, or enclosing words in backticks : `. I've put your code from the comments in.

Comment: @jrturton: Good job of formatting.  I was trying to do it while using a mobile device.  But not as easy and I saw you made the change.

Comment: Yes, nicely formatted questions go out the window when posting from your phone, don't they? I feel your pain.

Comment: Thankyou for the help jrturton.  I will do that in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You presented your 3rd VC (going from 2 to 3) using modalviewcontroller.  But then you tried to go back to 2nd VC (from 3rd to 2nd) using another modalVC.  That will not let you go back to the previous instance of 2nd VC.  You need to use dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimated method to do this.  Checkout Apple website on modalviewcontroller class reference for detail info on this.

Comment: I have no trouble going from 2->3 and 3->2.  Its only when I visit the third and then try to go back to the first (1>2>3>2--/-->1).

Comment: Can you do this test for me before I can further assist you:
On VC2, create an instance variable say an NSString, then assign some text to it.  Then move from 2->3.  And then move back from 3->2.  Now find out if that instance variable string still hold the text that you assigned to it before.

Comment: Almost forgot an important detail in my previous message.  By "assign" I meant to use a UITextField to get the input from you dynamically during running time and then assigning to that NSString.

Comment: It doesn't save.  (when typing on 2, then moving to 3, and then going back to 2)

Comment: That confirmed on my first explanation.  I would go ahead and replace your code in goBack method with this line (as also suggested by Darren's):
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, would you select it as your answer by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user523234, all you need to do is call

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

in the

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
```

method of the 3rd view controller, instead of what you're doing, which is creating another instance of the 2nd view controller and presenting it.

The reason it's not working now, is because when you press the done button in the 2nd view controller it calls

```
 - (IBAction)done:(id)sender 
{ 
   [self.delegate flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:self]; 
}
```

which is sending a message the 2nd view controller's delegate, which you haven't set in the case where you're going from 3->2.